# How to create repository in GitLab server using Bash?

Tags: bash, gitlab, repository

To create an empty repository named `some-example-repository` in a self-hosted GitLab server, I wrote the following bash method:

```
create_repository() {
    repo_name="$1"
    
    # load personal_access_token (from hardcoded data)
    personal_access_token=$(echo "$GITLAB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" | tr -d '\r')
        

    # Create the repository in the GitLab server
    { # try
        output=$(curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://127.0.0.1/api/v4/projects?private_token="$personal_access_token" -d "{ \"name\": \"$repo_name\" }")
        echo "output=$output"
        true
    } || { # catch
        true
    }
}
```

However, it is not functioning reliably, and occasionally it indicates a limit is reached. Hence, I would like to ask: *how could I reliably create an empty GitLab repository in a self-hosted GitLab server using Bash and a personal access token?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the [API limits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/rate_limits.html) to see if you are hitting that. Most likely, if you are doing this in a `for` loop, you might need to sprinkle in some `sleep 60` to slow things down.

I've created a hundred repos once before, but I was being paranoid and used `sleep 300` between creations.